# Ionic FB account kit login with sms

Tags: angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I work with FB account kit and I get error on button click : **AccountKit SDK was not initialized. Call AccountKit.init first**. And I realize when i test in browser when I come to same page and do refresh and click button its working without error. Or maybe someone can help me with code with FB account kit:

```
.controller('RegistrationCtrl', function($scope, $http,  $ionicPopup) {

   AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
      AccountKit.init(
              {
                appId:mycode,
                state:"{{csrf}}",
                version:"v1.0"
              }
            );
             console.log("{{csrf}}")

          };

      $scope.loginWithSMS = function() {

      AccountKit.login("PHONE",{}, loginCallback);



    function loginCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
              document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
              document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
              document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
            }
            else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {

            }
            else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {

            }

          }

    }
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $scope.data = {};
        $http.post(app4travel.apiUrl + '/register_mobile')
          .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            console.warn('Sent')
            console.warn(response)
            console.warn(status)
            $scope.response = response.data;
        })
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem, i just called Account Kit.init function in index.html(main) and it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
      AccountKit.init(
              {
                appId:id,
                state:"{{csrf}}",
                version:"v1.1"
              }
            );
             console.log("{{csrf}}")

          };

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, In the FB's document:

CSRF protection: The {{csrf}} placeholder above should be replaced with a non-guessable value which should originate in the app's server, and be passed to the login flow. It is returned back to the app client unchanged, and the app client can pass it back to server to verify the match with the original value.

**Secondly**: Check why: AccountKit.init not called.